# Is it reasonable to make a single page design for a blog?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, wordpress-theming, single-page-application

I have a moderate level experience on HTML, PHP, CSS, Javascript and WordPress development. So I decided to create my own theme for my personal blog. I'm writing tutorials, snippets and tech news on my blog.

In fact I prefer using new design trends like single page apps. Letting users to navigate between homepage to a post or a post to another post without reloading whole page. I think using WordPress Rest API and AngularJS would be adequate.

My actual question; is it creating a SPA theme for a simple blog is sensible? Can using WP REST API for this purpose increase or reduce my server load and page load time?

Answer (score 1):

**Is it sensible?**  Sure, if that's how you want it to work.

**Can using WP REST API for this purpose increase or reduce my server load and page load time?**  Yes it can either increase *or* reduce your server load time.  It comes down to your actual implementation, which until you implement it wont do either.

Most blogs are fairly simple with very little html/css/js and most of the content (i.e. bytes that must be transferred over the wire) is in any media that is included as part of your articles.  If you are only considering it for the purposes of reduced server load or page load time, there are a lot of other techniques that would probably prove more beneficial than converting your entire app to SPA (e.g. optimizing your static content or serving it from a CDN).  Of course I don't know your exact situation and without knowing more, no one is really going to be able to help you much more.

If you have a specific change to an existing you would like for us to compare, that's something Stack Overflow would be much better at for you.  Right now we're just guessing what your situation is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Server load and page loading time is important to mee. But my main concern is **user experience** which is affected by server load and page loading time.